Как сделать спуск строки каждые два элменета?
У меня есть кортеж, например:
(2, "Крутой чел", 3, "Награда 1")

Мне нужно чтобы получился вывод:
Награда #2 - Крутой чел
Награда #3 - Награда 1

Возможно ли это как то сделать?
Я пробовал обычный for, но получал вывод:
2
Крутой чел
3 
Награда 1


Извиняюсь, кортеж

Покажите код, как вы делали

@Ninterno, кнопка править для кого?

@MBo, а смысл? По выводу и тексту очевидно, что for x in t: print(x) - какая польза отвечающим от этой информации?

@Qwertiy Ну так может быть, достаточно будет подсказать, что каждый второй принт без перевода строки делать или ещё что. То, что ты написал - питонично, но ньюбу сразу слишком много незнакомого

@MBo, а что мешает это подсказать без этого кода в вопросе?

tio.run
x = (2, "Крутой чел", 3, "Награда 1")

for i,t in zip(x[::2], x[1::2]):
  print(f"Награда {i}: {t}")

Награда 2: Крутой чел
Награда 3: Награда 1


Можно распаковать кортеж в переменные. А потом вывести их в любой последовательности. Примерно так:
# Кортеж
awards = (2, "Крутой чел", 3, "Награда 1")

# Распаковка в переменные
r, b, c, h = awards

# Вывод в любой последовательности и в любом порядке
print(r, b)
print(c, h)


Переменных должно быть столько же сколько элементов в коллекции.

У меня есть база данных, в которую можно добавлять/забирать награды.

Возможно ли каким-то образом по другому?

Достаточно пройтись по кортежу с шагом 2 и на каждой итерации находить номер награды и саму награду
awards = (2, "Крутой чел", 3, "Награда 1")
for i in range(0, len(awards), 2):
    awardno = awards[i]
    award = awards[i + 1]
    print(f"Награда #{awardno} - {award}")

Хотя скорее всего намного проще изменить то как именно данные хранятся
